# I’m stuck on the android studio

Tags: android

Hiya guys I’ve developed the code for an android game app, this is the 1st one I have attempted so please tell me in the simplest terms possible lol, basically the coding is finished but I am really struggling with getting my head around the android studio to set it up and test it any help would be greatly appreciated thank you

I’ve got into the android studio and opened a new project now I’m completly lost with where to go next

Comment: I hope this will help https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial

Comment: https://developer.android.com/courses for beginners like you.

Comment: If you've already written the code you don't need android studio. You can install your app from the command line.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.